# Need help on using takeUntil() and Observable.fromEvent() Methods

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/let-s-learn/lets-learn-tcp-servers-in-nodejs-using-observables-cac538012eac) to create Reactive TCP server in Nodejs

here's code that i've been working on

```js
const Rx = require('rxjs')
const net = require('net')
const uuid = require('uuid');

module.exports  = () => {

        const sockets = new Map();
        const ids = new Map();

        const GetSocket = _id => sockets.get(_id);
        const GetId = _socket => ids.get(_socket);

        const SetSocket = _socket =>{
            _socket.setEncoding('utf8');

            const _id = uuid();
            sockets.set(_id, _socket);
            ids.set(_socket,_id);
            return _id;
        };

        const server = net.createServer({ allowHalfOpen: true });
        const socketStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(server, 'connection');

        const RemoveSocket = socket = () => {
            console.log("connection closed && removing socket from Map");
            const id = ids.get(socket);
            sockets.delete(id);
            ids.delete(socket)
        };
        const socketObservable = socket => SetSocket(socket) &&
            Rx.Observable
            .of({
                action: 'CONNECTION',
                socket: GetId(socket)
            })
                .merge(
                Rx.Observable
                    .fromEvent(socket,'data')
                    .map(d=>{
                        try {return JSON.parse(d);}
                        catch (e) {
                            console.log(e);
                            return d;
                        }
                    })
                    .map(msg=>{
                        return Object.assign({action:msg,socket:GetId(socket)})
                    })
                )
            .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'close').map(d=>{
                console.log("!!!! Should remove !!!");
                RemoveSocket(socket);
            }));

        const Print = ()=>{
            //ids.forEach(id=> console.log(GetSocket(id)));
            console.log("total connected socket : " + ids.size);
        };

        const startServer = port => server.listen(port) &&
            socketStream
                .flatMap(socketObservable);
        
        return {startServer, Print , stop: () => server.close()};
    };
```

and here's my test result(just sending test msg and connect/reconnect to server )

```js
{ action: 'CONNECTION',
  socket: '8989b581-dc54-479b-a8c0-870cc8103c5b' }
total connected socket : 1
{ action: { test: 1 },
  socket: '8989b581-dc54-479b-a8c0-870cc8103c5b' }
total connected socket : 1
{ action: { test: 2 },
  socket: '8989b581-dc54-479b-a8c0-870cc8103c5b' }
total connected socket : 1
{ action: 'CONNECTION',
  socket: 'b868104b-d1cf-41c9-950f-472f63bac27a' }
total connected socket : 2
{ action: { test: 1 },
  socket: 'b868104b-d1cf-41c9-950f-472f63bac27a' }
total connected socket : 2
{ action: 'CONNECTION',
  socket: 'b9a579fe-3715-4952-aaf7-d7f64a0bea99' }
total connected socket : 3
```

Everything working fine till detecting socket close event by **TakeUntil()**
I tried using **takewhile()** by simply adding counter like this **TakeWhile(cnt < 5)**
and socket stream completed as expected.

this is my first attempt to make something with Node.js and feel like i'm missing something.

can anyone help me to understand why takeUntil() is not working here?
Thank you :)

Comment: just tested takeUnitl() Method with Rx.Observable.timer() and it worked fine.
I think the issue is using Rx.Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'close')..

Comment: I don't see where you ever `subscribe` to your observable in `startServer`

Comment: You're using `.fromEvent(socket, 'close').map(...)` but you're not returning anything from the `map`'s callback.

Comment: @Brandon my subscription code in a different module.

Comment: @martin hmm I thought `map()` method can return anything. which means in my code it's returning a method that takes 'close' evnet and returns void function.  By changing `takeUntil()` line to this `.takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(5000).map(_=>RemoveSocket(socket)));`
  works fine.

Comment: Are you sure close is the correct event?  It does not look like that event ever triggers

Comment: @Brandon Thank you for the hint!
I changed 'close' to 'end' and it's working as expected.
however, there's one question remains. when do I use 'close' event?? I was confused by Node official doc https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_close_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my confusion was from understanding `'close'` and `'end'` events

`'end'` event gets triggered when the client disconnected or server calls `socket.end(..)` when server receives [FIN packet](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-TCPs-FIN-and-RST-packets)

and `'close'` event gets called after `socket.destroy()`

if anyone wants to see all socket events in action, I recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuGmMmNtPmQ)

@Brannon, Thank you for pointing out the right event usage and thank you, everyone, for helping me out with this!!

also just in case, anyone wants working TCP server code.

dependency : rxjs 5.5.0

```js
const Rx = require('rxjs');
const net = require('net');
const uuid = require('uuid');

module.exports  = () => {

    const sockets = new Map();
    const ids = new Map();

    const GetSocket = _id => sockets.get(_id);
    const GetId = _socket => ids.get(_socket);

    const SetSocket = _socket =>{
        _socket.setEncoding('utf8');
        const _id = uuid();
        sockets.set(_id, _socket);
        ids.set(_socket,_id);
        return _id;
    };

    const server = net.createServer({ allowHalfOpen: true });
    const socketStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(server, 'connection');

    const RemoveSocket = socket  => {

        const id = ids.get(socket);
        sockets.delete(id);
        ids.delete(socket)

        console.log("[server.js] socket closed..");
    };
    const socketObservable = socket => SetSocket(socket) &&
        Rx.Observable
            .of({
                action: 'CONNECTION',
                socket: GetId(socket)
            })
            .merge(
                Rx.Observable
                    .fromEvent(socket,'data')
                    .map(d=>{
                        try {return JSON.parse(d);}
                        catch (e) {
                            console.log(e);
                            return d;
                        }
                    })
                    .map(msg=>{
                        return Object.assign({action:msg,socket:GetId(socket)})
                    })
            )
            .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'end')
                .map(()=>RemoveSocket(socket)));

    const Print = ()=>{
        //ids.forEach(id=> console.log(GetSocket(id)));
        //ids.clear();
        console.log("total connected socket : " + ids.size);
    };

    const startServer = port => server.listen(port) &&
        socketStream
            .flatMap(socketObservable);

    console.log("[server.js] Starts Started" );
    return {startServer, Print , stop: () => server.close()};
};
```